# How to convert docx to html file using open xml with formatting

Tags: c#, html, openxml

I know there are lot of question having same title but I am currently having some issue for them I didn't get the correct way to go.

I am using Open xml sdk 2.5 along with [Power tool](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) to convert `.docx` file to `.html` file which uses `HtmlConverter` class for conversion.

I am successfully able to convert the `docx` file into the `Html` file but the problem is, html file doesn't retain the original formatting of the document file. eg. *Font-size,color,underline,bold* etc doesn't reflect into the html file.

Here is my existing code:

```
public void ConvertDocxToHtml(string fileName)
{
   byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
   using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
      using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
      {
         HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
         {
            PageTitle = "My Page Title"
         };
         XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);
         File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Test.html", html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
      }
    }
 }
```

So I just want to know if is there any way by which I can retain the formatting in converted HTML file.

I know about some third party APIs which does the same thing. But I would prefer if there any way using open xml or any other open source to do this.

Comment: PowerTools for Open XML just released a new HtmlConverter module that contains an open source, free implementation of a conversion from DOCX to HTML formatted with CSS. The module HtmlConverter.cs supports all paragraph, character, and table styles, fonts and text formatting, numbered and bulleted lists, images, and more. See http://bit.ly/1bclyg9

Answer (score 9):

PowerTools for Open XML just released a new HtmlConverter module.  It now contains an open source, free implementation of a conversion from DOCX to HTML formatted with CSS.  The module HtmlConverter.cs supports all paragraph, character, and table styles, fonts and text formatting, numbered and bulleted lists, images, and more.  See https://openxmldeveloper.org/

Comment: http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/transform-docx-to-htmlcss-with-high-fidelity-using-powertools-for-open-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Your end result will not look exactly the way your Word Document turns out, but [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628051.aspx#XHtml_Intro) might help.

Comment: This does not not convert formatting, such as paragraph fonts, or character fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to find an external tool to help you do this, like [Aspose Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use OpenXML Viewer extension for Firefox for Converting with formatting.
http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com
This works for me. Hope this helps.