# How to read msword file along with images, styles etc whole document?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read the msword (.doc/.docx) file whole content which having images, styles, text everything in asp .net using c#.

I used to write following code it works fine.

```
//   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
string filePath1 = @"G:\ABOUT.docx";
object file = filePath1;
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file,
                 ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                 ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                                 ref nullobj);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1 = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
string m_Content = doc1.Content.Text;

txtbook.Text = m_Content;
doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
```

but it is unable to read image files.

Please help I want to save whole content in database as html format and retrieve it in html format.

Comment: Open xml sdk is good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This might not be the direct cause of your problem, but it needs to be mentioned and it's too long for a comment.*

You are using Office automation to access Word documents from an ASP.NET application. [This is not officially supported by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

So, apparently, the solution to your problem is to

- use a third-party library to [convert your docx files to html files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20750192/87698) and then
- read the html file into your database.

Answer (score 0):

> doc1.Content.Text

You can't use MS Word document content text, as it is not in the HTML format. (Which is require to display image and style on the ASP.NET web page)

### Option 1

You can either convert document to HTML using Word Interop and get HTML markup in literal (Textbox won't work here)

### Option 2

Use something like Google Doc viewer to view your Word document. There are paid viewers too, like Aspose, which you can use to view Word Document on ASP.NET site http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx

In either case, you need to google and get more information on approaches, and implement for your ASP.NET website