# How to retain .docx format as email body using c#?

Tags: c#

in my project I have a requirement where in I have to get the body of the email from a .docx file, retaining the format as it is. Can anyone suggest any way to do that without much hassle. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to retrieve .docx file data to email body?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750192/how-to-convert-docx-to-html-file-using-open-xml-with-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look more into converting the .docx file into .html and then setting it as email body.
Taking inspiration from this answer [How to convert docx to html file using open xml with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750192/how-to-convert-docx-to-html-file-using-open-xml-with-formatting)

so your logical steps would be 
1. Convert the docs into html
2. Set the html as the body of your email
3. Send the email

Comment: Hi parv, thanks for the answer. Can you please suggest if I can make it work using Microsoft. Office. Interop. Word DLL too or not?