# Microsoft office interop word parse equation object and oMath objects as images instead of html

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, office-interop, file-conversion

I have a docx file that I try to parse into HTML which works pretty good using microsoft office interop library.
when there are some math equations in the docx file it parse them as images.

My problem is that when I print it afterwards it looks pixelated, but when I print the doc file itself it looks good.

Is there a way to parse them as native text (some divs and spans with css) instead of images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best what you could try is to play with different arguments that can be passed to the [Document.SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) method.

Also you may consider using the Open XML SDK instead of automating Word. See [How to convert docx to html file using open xml with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750192/how-to-convert-docx-to-html-file-using-open-xml-with-formatting) for more information.